# android eclipse an auto generate edittext when other edittexts have the given input

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have 3 edittext, 1 input price, 1 the percentage and the last one for the result of them both.It works perfectly, but when i delete the input from 2nd edittext the app will crash .Any idea where did i do wrong?or a better way to implement this. I want it works either the edittext filled and emptied by the user.

Here is the code::

```
public class Mastercode extends Activity implements TextWatcher ,AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener/*,View.OnClickListener*/{
    int tumbal1,tumbal2,tumbal3,tumbal4;
    EditText ethint1, etpersen2, textvDP1;
    Button bkalkulasi1;
  //  private final String[] items ={"Zona 1","Zona 2","Zona 3"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simulasikredit);
        ethint1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ethint);
        etpersen2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpersen);     
        textvDP1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textvDP);
        bkalkulasi1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bkalkulasi);
        // NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
         //((EditText) findViewById(R.id.ethint)).setText(format.format(ethint1));
        // ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.textvDP)).setText(format.format(textvDP1));        
        etpersen2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String text1 = ethint1.getText().toString();
                String text2 = etpersen2.getText().toString();
                 int input1 = Integer.valueOf(text1);
                    int input2 = Integer.valueOf(text2);                    
                if (text1.length() != 0) {    
                    int output = (input1 * input2) / 100;
                    textvDP1.setText(""+output /*+ ""*/);                                    
                }
                else if(text2.length() == 0/*trim().equals("")*/){
                    String input3 = Integer.toString(input2);
                    textvDP1.setText(""+input3);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
```

logcat log:

```
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:433)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:422)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:682)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at com.m4nd1r1tun45f1n4nc3.abcdefg.Mastercode$1.onTextChanged(Mastercode.java:43)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:6172)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:6316)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:889)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:352)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:583)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:174)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:120)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:247)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:73)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-16 14:43:12.331: E/AndroidRuntime(609):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDITTED CODE:

```
etpersen2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String text1 = ethint1.getText().toString();
                String text2 = etpersen2.getText().toString();
                int input1 = 0;
                int input2 = 0;
                if(text1.length()>0)
                      input1 = Integer.valueOf(text1);
                if(text2.length()>0)
                      input2 = Integer.valueOf(text2);                
                if (text1.length() != 0) {    
                    int output = (input1 * input2) / 100;
                    textvDP1.setText(""+output /*+ ""*/);                                    
                }
                else if(text2.length() == 0/*trim().equals("")*/){
                    /*String input3 = Integer.toString(input2);*/
                    textvDP1.setText(""/*+input3*/);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
```

its now working, thanks guys

Comment: you call `int input2 = Integer.valueOf(text2);` when text2 is empty

Comment: @georgesamuel Can you post your error log?

Comment: @Pooja Gaonkar its because when we delete the value given, emptied the edittext the code still runs and then catch " " or empty as an integer, while " " cant be an integer.I mean its a NumberExceptionFormat

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Yes,thats where i got stuck, any idea ?i mean example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this two lines

```
int input1 = Integer.valueOf(text1);
int input2 = Integer.valueOf(text2);
```

to

```
int input1=0;
int input2=0;
if(text1.length()>0)
  input1 = Integer.valueOf(text1);
if(text2.length()>0)
  input2 = Integer.valueOf(text2);
```

Because ValueOf(-) will throw **NumberFormatException**  if the string cannot be parsed as an integer.

Here is the docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If input was empty this line will throw error

```
int input2 = Integer.valueOf(text2);
```

instead change to ,

```
if(! text2.equals("")){
   int input2 = Integer.valueOf(text2);
}
```